# SQL Distinct Query for Two Tables

Tags: sql, mysql

### Table1:

```
id  -  name  -  address
-----------------------------
1   -  Jim   -  Some Street    
2   -  Adam  -  Some Street    
3   -  ABC   -  Some Street
```

### Table2:

```
id  -  job  -  finished_by
---------------------------
1   -  ABC  -  2    
2   -  EFD  -  3    
3   -  XYZ  -  2    
4   -  BVC  -  1
```

In the above two tables Table1.id and Table2.finished_by are supposed to be linked.

For, eg in table 2, job ABC was finished by Adam.

My objective is to select `DISTINCT` records from Table 2.

and the result should output all the job completed by each of the persons.

I have this query so far:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.finished_by = table1.id
     LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This joins the Tables side by side, but how do i edit the query to make it display only distinct records, so that the output is:

```
id  -  job  -  id  -  name
----------------------------
1   -  ABC  -  2  -  Adam    
2   -  EFD  -  3  -  ABC    
4   -  BVC  -  1  -  Jim
```

Update:

So, i've did some googling and made some changes to my query:

SELECT DISTINCT finished_by FROM table2
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.finished_by = table1.id
         LIMIT 0 , 30

But, it seems that only first line of the query is executed since, i dont see the LEFT JOIN table.

May be this query needs a bit more finishing??

More Updates:

So, from some very distinguished members of StacKOverflow it has been brought to my notice that my logic is totally wrong.. So, i'll try to explain what i am trying to achieve in simple words and not program/code. May be that way i can be fetch a quick solution.

So, there's my Company: CompanyA
people like Jim, Adam etc work for CompanyA.. But, CompanyA sends Jim, Adam etc.. to work for another Company.. Say Company1

Jim, Adam etc can be sent to work for multiple such companies. Say Jim is sent to work for Company1 twice and Adam was sent to work for Company1 thrice.

Table 2 maintains records of how many time a person went to work for Company1 in the following format:

### Table2: (Ref: Company1)

```
id  -  job  -  finished_by  -  Date  
------------------------------------
1   -  ABC  -  2    -  10 Oct
2   -  EFD  -  3    -  11 Oct
3   -  XYZ  -  2    -  12 Oct 
4   -  BVC  -  1    -  13 Oct
```

Now, my objective is simple, The reports need to be generated as follows for Company1:

- List the persons we sent to Company1 (in Alphabetic Order)
- This list should include No. of times the person went (and Dates)
- Should also Include the job he did there while he was working for Company1

For, eg an Ideal Output/Report would be:

### Name of Employee  -  Job Description  -  Dates

ABC               -  EFD              - 11 Oct

Adam              -  ABC, XYZ         - 10 Oct, 12 Oct

Jim               -  BVC              - 13 Oct

I can do all the basic reporting, But i judt dont know how to Convert the numbers that are sitting into Table2 in finished_by coloumn into their respective names from table1

I hope i'm clear with my question now.

Thanks, Everyone!!

I really appreciate your time and effort

Comment: Distinct in terms of what? The query as you've posted it already includes each row in `table2` only once.

Comment: VoteyDisciple is correct -- there's no reason for you to be getting duplicate TABLE_2 records unless there are more than one TABLE_1 record related to the TABLE_2 record.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking for. All records in table 2 are distinct already, so what's the problem with your existing query? Why do you want to exclude the XYZ record?

Comment: Hello everyone, the result should be DISTINCT on the basis of "finished_by" field...

Comment: @Sorpigal, if you have a look at the finished_by coloumn you can see that all records are not DISTINCT in this coloumn for eg. 2 is repeated two times.. I just need to be able to avoid this suplication..

Comment: Your usage of "distinct" is at odds with the way it is commonly used in SQL. Since job is in the result set and job is unique for each record the records are distinct.

Comment: In your example, Adam finished two jobs. How did you decide which of the two would get included in the output?

Comment: @VoteyDisciple, @Sorpigal: Thanks for your comments.. Now, it seems i'm heading into the wrong direction... I'll update the Question to rectify this error.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple: So, far there is no criteria for that, my programs logic requires just the distinct records. is it possible at all? Please pardon my silly questions, but i'm still a student and just a starter...

Comment: You've so far given two opposing criteria for this query. First, it will return only one row per distinct `finished_by` value. Second, you can't tell us which rows you actually want. The problem is: if you don't know what data you want, it's impossible to tell MySQL. Let's try the question this way: what are you going to do with the values you're getting from `table2`?

Comment: I agree with you totally VoteyDisciple, i'm quite confused here.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple: Please see the update 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your latest update, it sounds like you want a comma-separated list of the "job" names and dates. MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function accomplishes that. So perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT table1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.job), GROUP_CONCAT(table2.date)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (t1.id = t2.finished_by)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

This will give you a list of all employees who did work, along with comma-separated lists of where they did work and when.

Keep in mind that there's no order to the values in each `GROUP_CONCAT` list. So you can't be sure, for example, that the first job listed corresponds to the first date listed. But if you wanted to keep that connection intact you'd want each job in a separate row anyway.

Comment: Ok, so this query is very close to what i'm looking for and this seems to solve my problem... May be it needs a little more finishing.. In the coloumns where i should get comma seperated values i'm getting values as follows:     [BLOB - 1B]      [BLOB - 7B]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.finished_by = table1.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

does this work?

Comment: Unless there are duplicates of the entire TABLE_1 records, it's very unlikely this will solve the issue.

Comment: Agreed, it just seemed as if they are asking the obvious as the JOIN should return distinct records as seen in the results they posted

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want all Table1 details, together with a count of all jobs they have finished from Table2. If so, try this:

```
select t1.id, 
       max(t1.name)    name, 
       max(t1.address) address, 
       count(t2.id)    finished_jobs
from Table1 t1 left outer join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.finished_by
group by t1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but the logic cannot be reversed.. This query needs to work from table2 to table1 approach only... Because there are some other details in table2 that need to be taken care of..

Comment: However, this query will help me in my project in some other way as well. Thanks for this Solution!!